# Is Qt Creator source code not included in Qt Src?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Although I chose to install source code when installing Qt, I could not find the source code for Qt Creator in the Src directory. Isn't the source code for Qt Creator included in Qt source? Isn't Qt Creator part of Qt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt and Qt Creator are both developed inside the Qt Project, but are still two separate projects. Qt Creator depends on Qt, but not the other way around, one can use Qt perfectly fine without Qt Creator. They are released independently and with different versioning.

The "sources” package in the Qt installer refers to the Qt source code only, not to Qt Creator. In the installer you’re offered different versions of Qt, all with their own “sources” packages, but only one Qt Creator (the latest one).

You can find the Qt Creator source code in the [Qt Download section](https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qtcreator/4.11/4.11.1/) (the source code archives end in .tar.xz/.tar.gz/.zip) or in the [Git repository](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-creator/qt-creator.git).